# Is there a way to reproduce zsh tab completion with readline

Tags: c, readline, tab-completion, zsh-completion

As the post subject’s says, I want to know if there is a way with GNU readline library in C to reproduce the colored background like zsh does when pressing tab key.
I want to add this feature for the shell, I am currently working on.

Comment: You might want to look into the `readline` library documentation, specifically at [custom completers](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#Custom-Completers) functionality. It is not intended for this, but looks like you could hijack it.

Comment: It is _totally_ intended for that, even mentioning filename completion specifically. (You beat me to the comment with the link.)

Comment: @Dúthomhas Oh, well, maybe I misunderstood the colored background thing

Comment: @EugeneSh. Lol, I mis-read stuff all the time for dumber reasons than that.  (I have no idea how to mess with colors and readline. IDK if it can be done easily.)

Comment: @Dúthomhas, I suspect that what Eugene meant is that custom completers are not meant to provide a means to *add coloring* in the context of tab completion.  And I would agree.  I'm not immediately seeing how that could even be hooked for adding coloring without hacking readline internals.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes... I /s/got/mis-read/ that.